# How should I calculate Ramp-up-period

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

There are many answers available but i am very confused as the Jmeter does't exactly produce what i am expecting

Test Case : Want to run the test for total duration 20 minutes. With throughput of 30 request/second.

I have two sets of thread groups with the following  thread properties :

```
Overall Constants Throughput timer : 1800 samples / minutes ( which is 30 request per second)
```

```
Thread group -1
Number of users : 150 users
ramp up period = 5 (Not sure what to keep here, 150 users/ 30 (request/sec) = 5)
loop count : infinite
scheduler ; lifetime = 1200 seconds (20 minutes)
```

```
Thread group -2
Number of users : 150 users
ramp up period = 5 (Not sure what to keep here, 150 users/ 30 (request/sec) = 5)
loop count : infinite
scheduler ; lifetime = 1200 seconds (20 minutes)
```

But when i run the Jmeter the throughput in the summary report is above **100 request/sec**

Is there something wrong with the thread setting values that i assign ?

EDIT: by overall I  mean the same level for all thread groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what does "Overall Constants Throughput timer" mean and it is also unclear what you're using as "Calculate throughput based on". If you have Constant Throughput timer at the same level as Thread Groups - you need to choose `all active threads (shared)`

[image]

If you have 2 invividual timers with default settings  - divide throughput by 2.

You may find [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) easier to use or if you don't mind using [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) there is [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) which provides easy way of defining workload patterns in terms of requests per second

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i was using Constant Throughput Timer for this active thread only, i have changed it to all active threads(shared) and it's working alright now